# Trying to include a class, but get "Undefined type"

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Writing a little shopping cart thing in raw php, but suddenly I get this problem.

```
<?php

include("models/m_template.php"); 

$Template = new Template(); //Problem is here "Undefined type "Template"

$Template->load("views/v_login.php");
```

Here's what I have in the file where template class is located

```
<?
//Template Class - handless all templating tasks (displaying templates, alerts, errors)

class Template
{
    //Constructor
    function __construct() {}

    //Functions
    function load($url)
    {
        include($url);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's because include command is wrong? I tried writing the same line without brackets, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try changing `<?` in the top of your `m_template.php`-file to `<?php`. Short open tags has been disabled as default since many versions back. It could be that it includes the file as text instead of PHP. If that's the case, you should actually see the PHP code if you right click on the page and select "View source"

Comment: Have you solved the issue yourself, tried it and didn't work, tried it and it worked or did you just leave after asking the question?

Comment: After searching some more it turned out that it was a problem with an inteliphense extension. Which had to be turned off.

Comment: So the error was only in the IDE? You never actually tested the code for real??

Comment: Did test, only changing the IDE worked.

Comment: For next time, if you get an error in your IDE, test the code without the IDE to make sure it's a real issue. IDE's and things like inteliphense are today really really smart and good, but they aren't 100% in all situations, so a good first cause of action would be to test without them involved.